# My app doesn't work after an update

Tags: mycelium-wallet

[image]

My app doesn't work, it seems all white and doesn't show anything. It doesn't let me do anything and I'm so worry because I have a few bitcoins in my wallet. What should I do to solve my situation?. I hope you help me to solve it

Comment: Contact the developer of the app. This is an issue for their customer support.

Comment: See https://mycelium-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003713712-How-do-I-restore-a-backup-